# branching team project

Tags: tfs, branch, team-project

I have the following at Source Control Explorer

TFSServer/teamCollection
 + teamproject

Is is possible to branch /teamproject to /teamproject-dev?  The output should be

TFSServer/teamCollection/
 + teamproject-dev

I tried and it gave me error:
TF10175: The team project folder $/teamproject-dev does not exist.  Contact your Team Foundation Server Administrator and ask that it be created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Top level folders in source control are reserved for team projects.  If you create a new "teamproject-dev" project you could branch the code from the existing "teamproject" into the new -dev project via the wizard.

Alternatively set up a proper branching structure inside teamproject.  Read the [TFS Branching Guide](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can convert team project into branch.

The above error is saying that you don't have access to create branch. First you create branch by getting help from TFS admin then try what you mentioned that should work fine.